# Not all Visible Communities shown in Communities list on Profile page

Tags: bug, profile-page

My Profile page shows 2 Communities:

[image]

When I "Edit list" it shows 3 "Visible Communities"

[image]

Is this because CS50 is Beta? If so, a "note" to that effect might improve the  UX.

Comment: That's really weird, I can [link to it](//cs50.stackexchange.com) but apart from that I can't find it anywhere: the site list, Area 51, or even profiles of its users.

Comment: Also, [cs50.se] has an `X` as a favicon, not an `edX` as in the picture. At least the `[cs50.se]` magic link works.